# 3Ds Max Viewport and Render Issue

Tags: 3ds-max

I rendered the image in Vray but the Render image differs the shown area of viewport.
i.e. The size of image does not look the same image size that in Viewport.

[image][image: Here is the image. please see the difference in the viewport visible area and Rendered Image]

Here is the image. please see the difference in the viewport visible area and Rendered Image

Comment: Move your near clipping plane closer

Comment: Also consider joining [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics?referrer=QKFO2qIfMkCKQcyqcR7pKw2)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that it appears that your safe frames are on, your render should be the same dimensions as shown within the active viewport.

It seems to me that most likely you're overriding 3ds' render dimensions in the Frame Buffer section of the VRay settings. Ensure that the box that says "Get resolution from MAX" is checked. See image:

[image]